# background animation colors for answers and comments

Tags: discussion, design, user-experience, jquery

It seems that on most every site on the network it is the same animation background color when going to an answer or comment link. It seems that only the three trilogy sites have different animation colors for this. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/218011), [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/303137), and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Click on those three links to see the difference. All other sites I've tried have the same animation color as SO.

With the new SO design and the [lack of orange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283819/3041194) now, maybe the design team should consider changes to the color they use for SO, but as well as adding more different color animations to other graduated sites.

For example [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug/5126#5126) has the same default color for this even though it's the in [third place](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) for most traffic. [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn/30741#30741) has the same default color for this even though it's in [second place](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questions) for most questions asked.

I know that the reason for this amazing jQuery animation is likely just to draw attention to the answer/comment that you are visiting, so it's not a huge deal what color it is as long as it does it's purpose. But maybe it should be improved with better fitting colors that more closely match the site you're on? Thoughts?

Comment: What will changing the colour do on other Sites ? Is this really necessary ? I do not think so